# wanted UML diagram editor

Tags: diagram, uml

[image]

Recently I found this sequence diagram image.
And it was astounding me, because I used to use power point to draw sequence diagram. 
Do you know what exact  editor can make this beautiful uml diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was made using [SparxSystems' Enterprise Architect](https://sparxsystems.com/).
The color of the elements is exactly the default color used by this tool.
See [this example](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/layoutofsequencediagrams.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at plantuml (http://plantuml.com/):

- uses a text file as input
- doesn't have a GUI
- has an online web server to try things: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Astah Community](http://astah.net/editions/community) we used for school, it's sadly discontinued  26 September 2018. It appears you can still download that version via a [mirror](https://www.filecluster.com/Astah-Community.html).